# How to compile and run a c program in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, gcc

compile using gcc that the compiled code be saved with a different name and run it. I need the commands

Comment: what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

To compile `file.c` and create executable `file` do

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o file file.c
```

If you need additional libraries, add them after the C file.
To run the program do

```
./file
```